# In Java I'm was doing an ArrayList with my class, but when I'm trying to use a function from side library, I get an error about Provided type

Tags: java, gson

I am creating an ArrayList with my own Pet class, but when I try to use a function from a side library, I get an error message. This is a necessary piece of code:

```
ArrayList<Pet> PetList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(getContext());
PetList = tinydb.getListObject("PETS", Pet.class);
```

Message error:

```
Required type:
ArrayList<Pet>
Provided:
ArrayList<Object>
```

There's a Pet class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Pet {
    public String name;
    public String birthday;
    public Animal type;
    public Bitmap photo;

    public Pet() {
    }
}
```

There's a function's code:

```
public ArrayList<Object> getListObject(String key, Class<?> mClass){
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ArrayList<String> objStrings = getListString(key);
    ArrayList<Object> objects =  new ArrayList<Object>();

    for(String jObjString : objStrings){
        Object value  = gson.fromJson(jObjString,  mClass);
        objects.add(value);
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `#getListObject` is returning a `List<Object>` which your `PetList` (naming conventions!) does not accept. That function should really be `public <T> ArrayList<T> getListObject(String key, Class<T> mClass) { ... }` in order to return the correct type.

Comment: gson can already parse and return a list. Dont use a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any improvements to the code beyond what is necessary, you should utilize the type provided by your `Class` parameter:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> getListObject(String key, Class<T> mClass){ //change 1
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ArrayList<String> objStrings = getListString(key);
    ArrayList<T> objects =  new ArrayList<>(); //change 2

    for(String jObjString : objStrings){
        T value  = gson.fromJson(jObjString,  mClass); //change 3
        objects.add(value);
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Regarding the changes above:

1. Introducing `<T>` is declaring a generic type parameter *on the method*. When we then declare `mClass` as a `Class<T>`, we say that `T` is an instance of the class type you passed. By returning `ArrayList<T>`, we're returning a list of objects that have the type you provided.
2. Our returned value is changed accordingly, so that we truly return a `List<T>`. The second `Object` is dropped in favor of the diamond operator `new ArrayList<>()`, as re-declaring the type is not necessary in Java 7+
3. We utilize the generic return value from `Gson#fromJson` which does a similar approach to what we've done above. This allows us to get a `T` value instead of just an `Object`, which we add to our result list.

As noted in the comments, there are means of retrieving list values from gson (e.g. a `TypeAdapter` or even type tokens), but the solution above is to demonstrate fixing the problem with raw types and invariant types for generics (`List<String> != List<Number>` for most contexts).

Comment: thank you, I'm make the same thing after you comment. But In line // change 2, need to change for:
```ArrayList<T> objects =  new ArrayList<T>();```

Comment: Diamond operator `ArrayList<T> objects =  new ArrayList<>(); //change 2`

Comment: You can use the diamond operator: `new ArrayList<>()`. I missed it since re-declaring the types hasn't been necessary since Java 6.